# GCE zone us-central1-a gone forever?

Tags: google-compute-engine

My Google Compute Engine virtual machine resides on a persistent disk which lives in us-central1-a. I did not migrate it before maintenance because I didn't know maintenance takes a couple weeks. So I've been waiting patiently for maintenance to conclude so I can use the VM again.

I used to get a warning that the zone is down for maintenance. But today I got this:

```
Error: The resource 'projects/(my project name)/zones/us-central1-a' was not found
```

Is this temporary or permanent? I have my scripts backed up so I can re-create the VM, but it will require quite a bit of computing time to rebuild my application. I just need to know whether to wait or re-start.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to contact Google regarding this, as they may be able to answer your question better than anyone on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this surprised you!

This zone was temporarily removed as part of the maintenance as we testing some processes.  It should reappear shortly.

Joe Beda (GCE Lead Engineer)

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Cloud Console planned outage time is Aug 17, 2013 12:00:00 PM - Sep 1, 2013 12:00:00 PM